# casting a struct pointer to void

Tags: void-pointers

`MonkeyStruct *mnkS = (MonkeyStruct*)malloc(sizeof(MonkeyStruct));
   void *vS = (void *)mnkS;
   ManStruct * manS = (ManStruct *)vS;`

is it necessary in the above code segment to cast mnkS to void first then assign in to void
   or we can simply do `void *vS=mnkS`

Answer (score 1):

Void pointer can be assigned to any data type.

```
void *ptr;    // ptr is declared as Void pointer
char cn;
int in;
float fn;
ptr = &cn;  // ptr has address of character data
ptr = &in;  // ptr has address of integer data
ptr = &fn;  // ptr has address of float data
```

Thus you can assign

```
void *vS=mnkS
```

without casting.